# Using awk or bash to parse lines

Tags: awk

I have a file that has these types of lines:

```
 M00677:223:000000000-AB9BD:1:1101:2086:16648    163     AY243312        66733   0       95M22S  =       66733   108     ACATCATACCGATAGGAATACAAGACACTTTGCCGGCGGTTGTAGATTTATCATATTTTTTCCCTACACATTCGTTACCATTTGTTTAAAATTTATATAACACTATATTTTTCTCTT      BBBBBFFFFFBBGGEGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGGGA00155555D5@55555DDGG@33333132334443B113B4BF4BC24BFH43B44B44443333444444B3??4B   NM:i:6  MD:Z:60C1A5T2C6A7A8     AS:i:65 XS:i:65    XA:Z:AY313847,+69566,95M22S,6;AY678276,+69234,95M22S,7;M35027,+69864,95M22S,7;
 M00677:223:000000000-AB9BD:1:1101:3187:21406    99      AY313847        80978   0       68M43S  =       80978   36      TTATTCCATCTGTGGAAAATAATACTCTGACATTATCGCTAATTGACACATCGGTGAGTGATCTGCCTCTACCTTCCTCCTCTTCTTTTTTCCCATATACCCGTGTACCCG    BBBABFFFFFFFAFFGGGGGGGFHHGFGFFHHCFAFFGFFGGHHHGHHGBHGEDEEFHHHHHHGHFHHHGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHFFEGHHHHBGHHHHGGGHHHHFG NM:i:2  MD:Z:0C61A5     AS:i:62 XS:i:61 XA:Z:AY678276,+80652,68M43S,2;M35027,+81282,68M43S,2;AY243312,+78151,68M43S,2;
```

I was to filter and only get the lines where the number following the AS:i: tag is bigger than the number following the XS:i: tag. So in this case only the second line should print.

I have tried to write a complicated script in bash but converting into array and then parsing ifs didn't work and sounds too complicated.

Can I do this with awk?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 2):

By assuming that:

- the field order doesn't change
- the groups of `AS:i:`, `XS:i:` and `XA:Z:` are present in every line
- these field delimiters are not repeated in any lines

then the following works for me:

```
awk -F"AS:i:|XS:i:|XA:Z:" '$2 > $3' data
```

by setting the field separator value and then testing each line's values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions about your data, mainly that the AS tag is always field 14 and the XS tag is always field 15 (space-delimited). If that's the case and I understand your question well, this should do it:

```
awk '{ split($14, as_parts, ":"); split($15, xs_parts, ":"); if (as_parts[3] > xs_parts[3]) print; }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is robust

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  split($0, foo)
  for (bar in foo) {
    split(foo[bar], baz, ":")
    if (baz[1] == "AS") asi = baz[3]
    if (baz[1] == "XS") xsi = baz[3]
  }
  if (asi > xsi) print
}
```

Comment: +1 for clarity and not having to make any assumptions about order or position of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Python and a regular expersion? Maybe something along the lines?

```
import re

regex1 = r"AS:i:(?P<as_val>\d*)"
regex2 = r"XS:i:(?P<xs_val>\d*)"

m = re.search(regex1, string1)
if m and m.group('as_val') is not None:
   asVal = float(m.group('as_val'))

m = re.search(regex2, string1)
if m and m.group('as_val') is not None:
   xsVal = float(m.group('xs_val'))

if asVal > xsVal ...
```

This is off the top of my head, but it should be pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
$ perl -lne '/AS:i:(\d+)\s*XS:i:(\d+)/; print if $2 < $1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `AS:i:` always comes before `XS:i:` in every line, this is the shortest `awk` 1-liner I can think of:

```
awk -F"[AX]S:i:" '$2 > $3' infile
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -F"[AX]S:i:" '$2 > $3' gattaca
M00677:223:000000000-AB9BD:1:1101:3187:21406    99      AY313847        80978   0       68M43S  =       80978   36      TTATTCCATCTGTGGAAAATAATACTCTGACATTATCGCTAATTGACACATCGGTGAGTGATCTGCCTCTACCTTCCTCCTCTTCTTTTTTCCCATATACCCGTGTACCCG    BBBABFFFFFFFAFFGGGGGGGFHHGFGFFHHCFAFFGFFGGHHHGHHGBHGEDEEFHHHHHHGHFHHHGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHFFEGHHHHBGHHHHGGGHHHHFG NM:i:2  MD:Z:0C61A5     AS:i:62 XS:i:61 XA:Z:AY678276,+80652,68M43S,2;M35027,+81282,68M43S,2;AY243312,+78151,68M43S,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is all you need:

```
awk -F'[: \t]+' '$27 > $30' file
```

or more flexibly with GNU awk and gensub():

```
awk 'gensub(/.*\sAS:i:([0-9]+).*/,"\\1","") > gensub(/.*\sXS:i:([0-9]+).*/,"\\1","")' file
```